# Do not understand why duplicate data is being copied into my url in react component

Tags: reactjs, duplicates

In my `App.js` (or main component) I am rendering my `Navbar` component

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/layout/navbar/Navbar';

import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In my `Navbar` I am rendering my `NavLinks` component and passing in as `props` the `menu`

```
import React from 'react';
import NavLinks from './NavLinks';

const menu = [
  { id: 1, label: 'Home', url: 'https://www.google.com/?client=safari' },
  { id: 2, label: 'Contact us', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com' },
];

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <NavLinks items={menu} />
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

In my `NavLinks` I bring in as props the `items` which is the menu we saw before and `map` through it and pass in as `props` `url` and `label`.

```
import React from 'react';
import NavLink from './NavLink';

const NavLinks = ({ items }) => {
  const links = items.map((item) => (
    <NavLink key={item.id} url={item.url} label={item.label} />
  ));

  return <ul>{links}</ul>;
};

export default NavLinks;
```

In my `NavLink` component I am creating a `Link` to the `url`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavLink = ({ url, label }) => {
  return (
    <li className='nav-item'>
      <Link to={url}>{label}</Link>
    </li>
  );
};

export default NavLink;
```

For some reason my `Link` has a path of multiple `google urls`. The url to the google homepage is duplicated many times. I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `my Link has a path of multiple google urls`?

Comment: Is this happened when you tried to click it multiple times?

Comment: well it basically has a url which is the the url homepage for google but it is duplicated so instead of ex. google.com it is google.comgoogle.comgoogle.com etc. And no it is just in there when I render the page first and I can see this in my DOM

Comment: `react-router-dom` `Link` components only link to internal URLs, i.e. links into your app. External URLs should use an HTML anchor `<a />` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **[Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) component is to Provides declarative, accessible navigation around your application**

If you use the `Link` component for the external URL, this will keep appending your URL to the previous ones.

**For navigating to an external URL, I would suggest you to use native HTML  tag instead:**

```
const NavLink = ({ url, label }) => {
  return (
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a href={url}>{label}</a>
    </li>
  );
};
```

**Working example:**

[image: Edit elastic-borg-kfbvv]

Comment: How come it appends to it though. I get that I can just use the `a` tag but why does it duplicate besides it being an external url and that I should not use Link for this

Comment: <Link/> component has a specific mechanism for navigating internally, if it acts the same as the normal <a/> tag... it obviously redundant.

Comment: With all due respect the response to saying `<Link/>` behaves differently to `<a/>` tag is redundant. I don't understand why it duplicates. The answer doesn't explain why a url `google.com` can become `google.comgoogle.comgoogle.com`.

Comment: Here is a quote from [react-router website](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) `A string representation of the Link location, created by concatenating the location’s pathname, search, and hash properties.`